# Unknown chromium error : -6

Tags: android, logcat

I am testing an app with the logcat in eclipse, after i click a button on a page, it appears "Unknown chromium error : -6" in logcat. Any way to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: It also appears "Rejecting registerization due to div-int/lit8 v0,v3(#2)" What's the problem? thanks